# Can this be solved with a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to extract the digits from between the words in this string.

```
110.0046102.005699.0008103.0104....
```

I want to extract 4 digits after dot (point/period).

- `110.0046`
- `102.0056`
- `99.0008`
- `103.0104`

I was wondering if this was possible to do with a regular expression or if I should just use other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// replace the variable $numbers with your numbers
$numbers = "110.0046102.005699.0008103.0104";
preg_match_all("#\d+\.\d{4}#", $numbers, $matches);
var_dump($matches); // outputting all matches
```

https://regex101.com/r/oG1dK1/1 -> you can see the regex in action here. The numbers are in the box **MATCH INFORMATION** on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(\d{1,}\.\d{4})
```

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/uJ1wU6/1